# how to supress log when query from hive table with Parquet format

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, parquet

first,i create a table with spark1.6.1 like this:

```
hiveContext.createDataFrame(rows, schema).write.mode(SaveMode.Append).saveAsTable(tableName)
```

second,when i query from my table like this:

```
hive> select dt from tablename limit 200;
```

it print a lot of log like this:
2016-12-9 10:41:11 INFO: parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: block read in memory in 1 ms. row count = 13
2016-12-9 10:41:11 WARN: parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader: Can not initialize counter due to context is not a instance of TaskInputOutputContext, but is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.TaskAttemptContextImpl
2016-12-9 10:41:11 INFO: parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: RecordReader initialized will read a total of 20 records.
2016-12-9 10:41:11 INFO: parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: at row 0. reading next block
2016-12-9 10:41:11 INFO: parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader: block read in memory in 1 ms. row count = 20
2016-12-9 10:41:11 WARN: parquet.hadoop.Par**2016-11-26**

```
2016-11-26
2016-09-02
2016-11-13
2016-11-13
2016-11-13
2016-11-13
2016-11-13
2016-11-13
2016-11-13
2016-11-13
2016-11-13
2016-11-13
2016-11-13
2016-11-13
2016-11-13
```

see the font in bold,it was part of my result.but it was mixed with the log info

but when query likie this :

```
hive> select dt from tablename group dt;
```

it was good

how to suppress the log  that i didn't need ?

Answer (score 0):

you need use this function "sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")"?